# Ruby on rails wkhtmltopdf css style sheets not rendering on production (linux) server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, wkhtmltopdf

In local development environment(windows) pdf with Css styles generated successfully. but in hosting linux server environment pdf generated without applying css styles.Below is my wkhtmltopdf (WickedPdf) config

```
WickedPdf.config = {
#:wkhtmltopdf => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/pdfbin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64",
:exe_path => "/home/software/.gems/bin/wkhtmltopdf",
:layout => "layouts/pdf.html.erb",
:margin => {    :top=> 40,
                :bottom => 20,
                :left=> 30,
                :right => 30},
:header => {:html => { :template=> 'layouts/pdf_header.html.erb'}},
:footer => {:html => { :template=> 'layouts/pdf_footer.html.erb'}}
#:exe_path => '/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
```

}

**for additional info :**

this is my dir structure i am on linux rails hosting app\views\layouts , inside layouts i am having pdf.html.erb , pdf_footer.html.erb , pdf_header.html.erb The above stuff works perfectly on my local windows development environment , but in production pdf generated without styles.so guys please help me to produce pdf with CSS styles

**app/views/layouts/pdf.html.erb**

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html dir="<%= (rtl?) ? 'rtl' : 'ltr' %>">
  <head>
    <% @direction = (rtl?) ? 'rtl/' : '' %>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> 
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag([@direction+'application', @direction+'_styles/ui.all'])%>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag(*get_stylesheets) %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag  @direction+"_layouts/pdf" %>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%="#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/stylesheets/#{@direction}_layouts/pdf.css" %>" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%="#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/stylesheets/#{get_stylesheets}.css"%>" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/stylesheets/#{@direction}_styles/ui.all.css"%>" media="all" />


  </head>
  <body>

    <%= yield %>

  </body>
</html>
```

**pdf.html.erb contains all styling information for rendering pdf , in hosting environment these styles are not fetching by wkhtmltopdf . so guys please help me**

Comment: What ever you do please check with wkthtmltopdf library first This will ensure you where you are going wrong in production and also I feel that `public` in the stylesheet declaration is not required specify your `hostname` followed by stylesheet path ignoring `public` aspect `wkhtmltopdf` will fetch those css for you

Comment: Hi Viren , i did as per your suggestion , but the output pdf is without css styles , is there any other way to trace the bug. for you info in devlopment environment wkhtmltopdf lib is present inside my own rails application , for ex app/pdfbin/wkhtmltopdf.exe  , but in production i used wkhtmltopdf provied bu hosting provider (/home/software/.gems/bin/wkhtmltopdf) , this was the only change i did for local and production environment.

Comment: Check your log when generating a pdf see if the request for css is logged by `wkhtmltopdf` . Also I asked you to do a test in `wkhtmltopdf` bcoz in past I have seen un-similarity in various version of `wkhtmltopdf` so just do check  whether what you are try to achieve is actually supported in that version of `wkhtmltopdf`

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with PDFKit when I was deploying my app on Heroku.
Now, it's working fine (I've included the binary to the project).

In my layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Page title</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <style type="text/css" media="all">
    <%= Rails.application.assets['my_css'].to_s.gsub(/\/assets/,"#{root_url}assets") %>
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

In the initializers:

```
# config/initializers/pdfkit.rb
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  if Rails.env.staging? || Rails.env.production?
    config.wkhtmltopdf = Rails.root.join('bin', 'wkhtmltopdf-amd64').to_s
  else
    config.wkhtmltopdf = '/Users/my_user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@my_project/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
  end
  config.default_options = {
    :page_size => 'A4',
    :margin_top => '0in',
    :margin_right => '0in',
    :margin_bottom => '0in',
    :margin_left => '0in',
    :orientation => 'Portrait'
  }
  # Use only if your external hostname is unavailable on the server.
  config.root_url = "http://localhost:3000" unless Rails.env.staging? || Rails.env.production?
end
```

Maybe that could help you... or someone else...

Comment: The config.root_url = .... line was the magic sauce for my css and images showing up. The reason was my production server was a unix socket, and manually specifying a http location helped it find the other resources.

Comment: Glad I could help... in a way I couldn't think about ;-)